# Working with FlagsEnum, ModelBinders and JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, custom-model-binder, enum-flags

How to modify the ModelBinder to work with FlagsEnum (Enum: byte)?
I'll show the code:

### Code

**Enum**

```
[Flags]
public enum TipoPessoaEnum : byte
{
    Comprador = 1
    ,
    Proprietario = 2
    ,
    GerenteAgencia = 4
}
```

**Class**

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public TipoPessoaEnum? Tipo { get; set; }
    // Other fields have been omitted
}
```

**Json**

```
{"Id":0,"Nome":"Teste Flags 02","Tipo":["Comprador","Proprietario"],"Genero":"Masculino","Escolaridade":"","EstadoCivil":"","RegimeCasamento":"","Telefones":[],"Emails":[],"Enderecos":[]}
```

**Model Binder**

> Works when **not use JSON**, both Enuns as FlagsEnuns.

```
public class CreditoImobiliarioModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName))
        {
            var values = GetValue<string[]>(bindingContext, bindingContext.ModelName);
            var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetNonNullableModelType();

            if (values != null && values.Length > 1 && (modelType.IsEnum && modelType.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false)))
            {
                long byteValue = 0;
                foreach (var value in values.Where(v => Enum.IsDefined(modelType, v)))
                    byteValue |= (byte)Enum.Parse(modelType, value);

                return Enum.Parse(modelType, byteValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    private static T GetValue<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(key))
        {
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            if (valueResult != null)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, valueResult);
                return (T)valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

### Question

As you can see, in class `PessoaViewModel`, the property `Tipo` can take multiple values​​ for `TipoPessoaEnum`.

Because the property `Tipo` can take multiple values​​, I am sending (in JSON format) an array of `Tipo` `"Tipo":["Comprador","Proprietario"]`. Which are the values ​​of enuns.

How to map my json array  `"Tipo":["Comprador","Proprietario"]` to my property `Tipo`??

**Model Binder**

In Method `GetValue<T>` of class `CreditoImobiliarioModelBinder` this `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Tipo");` **returns null**??